# Seg Fault only happens every couple of runs

Tags: c++, c++11

this is my first question I have posted, and I made sure to check other threads with similiar topic titles and the same problems, however none of the solutions have helped me thus far.

Problem:  Upon compilation via a makefile included below

```
OBJ = hw1.o

hw1: $(OBJ)
    g++ -g -o hw1 $(OBJ)

hw1.o: 

./PHONE:
    clean

clean:
    rm hw1.o
```

I receive a segmentation fault about every 3 runs.  The solutions I have seen on this site have included moving `linked_list*` objects outside of the main program, however when I tried this, it gave me segmentation faults every run.

Below is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

struct linked_list
{
    int data;

    void set_data(int d) { data = d; }
    int get_data(void) {return this->data; }
    void set_next(linked_list* ll) { this->next = ll; }
    linked_list* get_next(void) { return this->next; }

    linked_list* next;
};

//linked_list* head;    this is where I moved the objects out of main
//linked_list* tail;    which cause seg faults every run
//linked_list* temp;

void print_linked_list(linked_list*, int);

int main()
{
    linked_list* head;
    linked_list* tail;
    linked_list* temp;
    std::ifstream data1, data2;
    int element = 0;            //elements from list
    int size_ll = 0;

    //Open data1.txt and check for errors
    //data1.txt contains elements to be added in to both data structures
    data1.open("data1.txt");
    if(data1.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Couldn't open data1.txt\nCheck that file exists...\n";

        return 0;
    }

    //Open data2.txt and check for errors
    //data2.txt contains elements which need to be deleted in both data structures
    data2.open("data2.txt");
    if(data2.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error Couldn't open data2.txt\nCheck that file exists...\n";

        return 0;
    }

    head->set_next(NULL);
    tail->set_next(NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 150; i ++)
    {
        data1 >> element;

        temp = new linked_list;
        temp->set_data(element);
        temp->set_next(NULL);

        if((size_ll % 50) == 0 && size_ll != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n\nPrinting current linked list (left to right, top to bottom):";
            std::cout << "\nCurrent size:   " << size_ll;
            std::cout << "\n\n";
            print_linked_list(head, 0);
            std::cout << "\n";
            std::cout << "End of current list.\n";
        }

        //handling linked list
        if(size_ll == 0)
        {
            head = tail = temp;

            size_ll++;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->set_next(temp);
            tail = temp;

            size_ll++;
        }
    }

    data1.close();
    data2.close();
}

//pass the next element of the linked list
void print_linked_list(linked_list* current, int lol)
{
    if(current == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    std::cout << std::setw(4) << current->get_data() << "  ";

    if(lol == 9)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        lol = -1;
    }

    print_linked_list(current->get_next(), lol+1);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running this under a debugger? What line is it segfaulting on?

Comment: When i use the GDB debugger, it never gives me a seg fault, making it very hard to trace

Comment: Core dump, then?

Comment: it seg faults before the main even happens

Comment: What is there in data1 and data2.txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you have written:

```
linked_list* head;
linked_list* tail;
```

and then you do:

```
head->set_next(NULL);
tail->set_next(NULL);
```

without initializing `head` nor `tail`. This is an UB

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing your linked lists. If you have them as static variables, they'll be zero-initialized, and the line `head->set_next(NULL)` will crash as it tries to dereference NULL.

With them defined in `main()`, they have random stack values. You'll crash on the same line if the stack value is an invalid address, but if it happens to contain an address that points into valid memory, you'll instead just start overwriting arbitrary memory.

Comment: Thank you very much, both these answers have helped me understand the error of my ways!